# Integration of the function $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{{9x}}{2}} \right)}}{{\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}}$

Tags: integration, limits

Let f be the function on $[-\pi,\pi]$ given by $f(0)=9$ and $f\left( x \right) = \frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{{9x}}{2}} \right)}}{{\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}}$ for $x\ne 0$. Find the value of $\frac{2}{\pi }\int\limits_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f\left( x \right)dx} $

My approach is as follow. The function is continuous at $x=0$. Hence it is contionuos for $[-\pi,\pi]$

$f\left( x \right) = \mathop {\lim }\limits_{x \to 0} \frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{{9x}}{2}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{{9x}}{2}} \right)}} \times 9 \times \frac{{\left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}}{{\sin \left( {\frac{x}{2}} \right)}} = 9$

$\frac{x}{2}=\theta$

$\frac{2}{\pi }\int\limits_{ - \pi }^\pi  {f\left( x \right)dx} $

$\int\limits_{ - \pi }^\pi  {\frac{{\sin \left( {\frac{{9x}}{2}} \right)}}{{\left( {\frac{{9x}}{2}} \right)}}dx}  \Rightarrow 2\int\limits_{ - \frac{\pi }{2}}^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\frac{{\sin \left( {9\theta } \right)}}{{\sin \left( \theta  \right)}}d\theta }  \Rightarrow 4\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\frac{{\sin \left( {9\theta } \right)}}{{\sin \left( \theta  \right)}}d\theta }  $

$ \Rightarrow 4\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\frac{{\sin \left( {8\theta  + \theta } \right)}}{{\sin \left( \theta  \right)}}d\theta }  \Rightarrow 4\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\frac{{\sin \left( {8\theta } \right)\cos \left( \theta  \right) + \cos \left( {8\theta } \right)\sin \left( \theta  \right)}}{{\sin \left( \theta  \right)}}d\theta } $

$ \Rightarrow 4\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\left( {\frac{{\sin \left( {8\theta } \right)\cos \left( \theta  \right)}}{{\sin \left( \theta  \right)}} + \cos \left( {8\theta } \right)} \right)d\theta } $

$\int\limits_0^{\frac{\pi }{2}} {\cos \left( {8\theta } \right)d\theta }  = 0$

How so I proceed form here as expansion of $sin(8\theta)$ is cumbersome.

Is their any formula of converting $sin(n\theta)$ in terms of $sin(\theta)$

Comment: $$\frac{\sin \left(\frac{9 x}{2}\right)}{\sin \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}=2 \cos (x)+2 \cos (2 x)+2 \cos (3 x)+2 \cos (4 x)+1$$

Answer (score 1):

Via $$\cos t={e^{it}+e^{-it}\over2},\qquad\sin t={e^{it}-e^{-it}\over2i}$$
you can easily prove that
$${\sin(9t)\over\sin t}=1+2\bigl(\cos(2t)+\cos(4t)+\cos(6t)+\cos(8t)\bigr)\ .$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{2 \over \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
{\sin\pars{9x/2} \over \sin\pars{x/2}}\,\dd x} =
{8 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\sin\pars{9x} \over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
{8 \over \pi}\,\Im\int_{0}^{\pi/2}
{\expo{9x\ic} - 1\over \sin\pars{x}}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.{8 \over \pi}\,\Im\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}
{z^{9} - 1 \over \pars{z - 1/z}/\pars{2\ic}}
\,{\dd z \over \ic z}
\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\\[5mm] = &\
\left.{16 \over \pi}\,\Im\int_{x\ =\ 0}^{x\ =\ \pi/2}\
{1 - z^{9} \over 1 - z^{2}}
\,\dd z\,\right\vert_{\ z\ =\ \exp\pars{\ic x}}
\end{align}
I'll "close" the integration around a quarter circle, of radius $\ds{1}$, in the complex plane first quadrant:
\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{{2 \over \pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}
{\sin\pars{9x/2} \over \sin\pars{x/2}}\,\dd x} =
-{16 \over \pi}\,\Im\int_{1}^{0}\
{1 - \ic y^{9} \over 1 + y^{2}}\,\ic\,\dd y
\\[5mm] = &\
{16 \over \pi}\int_{0}^{1}{\dd y \over 1 + y^{2}} =
{16 \over \pi}\,{\pi \over 4} = \bbx{4} \\ &
\end{align}